# Асинхронная работа поллинга телеграм бота и пайтон корутины

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp, aiogram

Изучаю асинхронность и aiogram решил сделать простого бота. Есть асинхронная функция, которая опрашивает сайт на статус код (request_site) через промежуток времени, а есть polling самого бота, как мне их подружить вместе асинхронно, т.к таботает либо то (запросы делаются ,статус код приходит, но не работают команды бота), либо другое.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(request_site())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.....

.....

import asyncio
async def async_patok_function():
    while True:
        #do something 
        print("hi")
        await asyncio.sleep(700)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(request_site())
    dp.loop.create_task(async_patok_function())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```